# SqlDataReader.GetBoolean returning incorrect value

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I have a column in a database table that stores 'bit' type. Values can be null, false or true. I am using a SqlDataReader object to read rows from this table and am successfully able to read all column values except this 'bit' column. The code looks like this:

```
if(!dataReader.IsDBNull(columnOrdinal))
{
    bool? value = dataReader.GetBoolean(columnOrdinal);
}
```

It is safe to assume the columnOrdinal value is correct since rest of the columns are being read as expected. 'value' is a nullable Boolean due to business requirement.

Problem: When the value of the column is 'false' in db, 'value' variable is set to 'true'.

The object model is set-up in such a way that I can't test what would be the case when column value is 'true', but I have a problem any way. I am clueless as to why would this happen, any help or pointers would be really appreciated.

Comment: try this : bool? value = dataReader["columnOrdinal"] as bool? ?? null; or

Comment: Values can be null, 0 or 1 actually, Not false or true. What data do you have?

Comment: I think you're incorrect. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getboolean%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) clearly states it won't perform any conversions. So it will read either 0 and return false, or 1 and return true, but not NULL.

Comment: @abatishchev - it will throw an exception if null.  There's nothing in the document that says it converts 0/1 to false/true, it says the underlying data must already be a boolean, so no conversion at all.

Comment: @Aniruddha - I've learnt to never assume when code is faulty, so in this case don't assume the columnOrdinal is correct.  Please show us the related code.  Having the DB Schema and SQL would also help.

Comment: @Will: The only way to my knowledge the underlying data to be true/false in SQL Server is to be bit 1/0.

Comment: @Will - I agree. However the code is bulky and has been in use for years, its safe to assume its doing the right thing since all other columns are read correctly. Basically I use SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable and from their calculate the right ordinal for each column. The column is of type bit, defaults to null.

Comment: @abatishchev - Thanks for your replies. The column type is bit, can be null. Other values are 0 and 1. The values shows up as false and true resp. in data grid that's why I used them above, in either case that's not the concern here. I am handling the null scenarios and converting the value to a Boolean the way it should be. My quandary is more about why I get true when in db it is set to '0'.

Comment: You can use `reader.GetOrdinal()` instead.

Comment: Also try `(bool)reader[i]` where `i` not a dynamically calculated ordinal from the schema but well-known number, say 34.

Comment: My bad, the code has been reading data from the db using a stored procedure and that stored procedure was always returning either null or 1. Sorry and thanks for all your replies guys.